# wxPython: Check if tree node has focus (TreeCtrl)

Tags: python, events, tree, focus, wxpython

Do not be intimidated by the code. It is really straightforward. (Run it if you want)

I am trying to figure out a way to do something when a tree node has focus. I know if I want to do something if the TreeCtrl has focus then it would be:

self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, some_function)

But I don't want that, I want it for tree node. Any help?

For my application, a pop up window would show up for every tree node selected, and disappears if the tree node loses focus.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(600, 400))
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
        self.tree = MyTree(self.leftPanel, 1, wx.DefaultPosition, (300, 300))
        self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelChanged, id=1)

        self.rightPanel = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)

        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.leftPanel, self.rightPanel)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer ( )
        sizer.Add ( self.splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND )
        self.SetSizer ( sizer )

        self.tree.SetFocus()

    def OnSelChanged(self, event):
        print 'Sel Changed'


class MyTree(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, panel, id, pos, size):
        self.panel = panel
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, panel, id, pos=pos, size=size, style=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)

        wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_EXPANDING(self,-1,self.OnItemExpanding)
        wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_COLLAPSED(self,-1,self.OnItemCollapsed)
        wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS(self,self.OnGotFocus)

        self.root = self.AddRoot('Root')
        self.SetPyData(self.root,0)
        self.SetItemHasChildren(self.root)
        self.Expand(self.root)
        self.SetImageList(wx.ImageList(16,16))

    def OnItemExpanding(self,evt):
        node = evt.GetItem()
        data = self.GetPyData(node)
        if data:
            for i in range(1,2):
                leaf = self.AppendItem(node,'%s.%s' % (data,i))
                self.SetPyData(leaf,'%s.%s' % (data,i))
        else:
            for i in range(1,2):
                leaf = self.AppendItem(node,'%s' % (i))
                self.SetPyData(leaf,'%s' % (i))
                self.SetItemHasChildren(leaf)

    def OnItemCollapsed(self,evt):
        self.DeleteChildren(evt.GetItem())

    def OnGotFocus(self,evt):
        print 'tree got focus'
        evt.Skip()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "This is a test")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want

```
...
    self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED,self.OnTreeSelectionChange)
    self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS,self.OnKillTreeFocus)

...
def OnTreeSelectionChange(self, evt):
    print "OnSelChanged:   ", self.GetItemText(evt.GetItem())
```

Comment: I have tried this before, it only worked for the first couple times, then it stopped working (the pop up window does not disappear anymore). I will try it again, and if it works I will accept your answer

Comment: So apparently I need to force the Pop up Window to disappear before creating another one.

Comment: what do you mean align it to the right? you can give it a position to pop up at ...

Comment: Well, the position origin starts from top left, but I want to have it start from right

Comment: ummm `wx.Dialog(None,-1,"A title",pos=(500,0))` ?

Comment: I got the display size (wx.DisplaySize) and subtract the size of pop up window instead